# Looking for a 90s YA horror anthology

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult, horror

I believe it was a compilation of stories from various authors, and I believe it was a series of multiple books. I am usually a very good Googler but so far have come up empty.

Some stories I remember:

1.) A creepy neighbor in a trash-filled house whose fat stomach has an evil mouth in it. (I believe he may also have collected faces.)

2.) A bored child agrees to trade bodies with a cat and it turns out maybe all cats are kids who have been tricked this way. Eventually he convinces another child to switch with him and is thankful to join that other child's family.

3.) A boy who goes into the scary space under his bed and is forced to become a goblin and kidnap other children to become goblins but misses his family and visits.

4.) The moonlight plays on a girl's wall in some magical way and entices her to leave her family to live on the moon forever.

I would be so grateful if this rings a bell with anyone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those sound like they're from *Bruce Coville's Book of Nightmares*, or possibly some other books in the series. I don't have it with me, but from the table of contents and excerpts on Amazon ([http://www.amazon.com/books/dp/0590461613](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0590461613)) these sound like the stories in question:

1. "The Fat Man" by Joe R. Landsdale. The fat man eats people, spits out their skin, and makes puppets that look like humans to imitate them.
2. Possibly "The Cat Came Back" by Lawrence Watt-Evans, but I don't really remember this story. It may have been in another book in the series
3. "There's Nothing Under the Bed" by Bruce Coville (excerpt here: http://www.brucecoville.com/books.asp?tid=143&spec=p ) - the main character gets pulled into the land of nightmares through a portal under his bed and is forced to distribute nightmares. He takes extras to his mean cousin.
4. "Drawing the Moon" by Janni Lee Simner. From the Amazon excerpts, seems like it was a boy, though, although I also remembered a girl. His parents were killed by a mugger, but he was convinced the moon had actually stolen them away. He wound up bargaining with the moon to bring them back, but was forced to stay with the moon in exchange.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!